# Создать таблицу в html-документе через js, используя данные json?

Tags: javascript, json

Нужно создать таблицу в html-документе, используя данные json (создать локальную модель данных) на чистом js. Итоговый вариант должен выглядеть как на картинке. Как это сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так а json то есть или его структуру тоже нужно придумать?

Comment: Нет его, дан только образец результата

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Принимаешь json в переменную(для примера локальная переменная `data`)

```
let data = {
  people1 : {
   name : "vasja",
   jan : 9,
   mar: 6,
   feb : 0
  },
  people2 : {
   name : "peta",
   jan : 1,
   mar: 63,
   feb : 10
  }
}
```

Далее вы должны запустить цикл по объекту и вписать их значения в таблицу. В примере реализована возможноть внесения значений в `tbody`, разберитесь и сделайте вывод значений в `thead`

```
function createTable() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var thead = document.createElement('thead');
  var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');


  for (var key in data) {
    var person = data[key];
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    for(var key in person) {

      var td = document.createElement("td");
      var cellText = document.createTextNode(person[key]);
      td.appendChild(cellText);
      row.appendChild(td);

    }

    tbody.appendChild(row);
  }

  body.appendChild(table);
  table.appendChild(thead);
  table.appendChild(tbody);
}

createTable();
```